# How to trigger a UNIX command upon build in Flash CS5 (to generate NaturalDocs documentation)?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, documentation-generation, flash-cs5

I'm using NaturalDocs to generate code documentation for a Flash project that we're developing with Flash CS5 on a Mac running 10.6.4.

Currently, I have an automator script I can click to trigger the UNIX script and generate the documentation, but I'd rather have it automatically generate the documentation whenever I compile.  (This is what NaturalDocs suggests as a general practice for generating code documentation.)

So, is it possible to trigger the UNIX command to generate the documentation alongside the build process in CS5?  I know other IDE's can do this sort of thing, but I don't see any (obvious) way to do it in CS5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not sure this still work, tried it once and it did.
http://julifos.wordpress.com/2010/03/12/run-command-line-from-jsfl/

hope this helps.